# TaskScheduler Number of tasks that still need to be processed

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I have a pool of servers that is used to load balance some work. This work is partitioned in discrete work items, however it's impossible to determine how much time a given work item will take.

Each server uses TPL to schedule the work on the work items.
To truly load balance the work I need to be able to determine how much each server has work items pending.

All I need is to get the number of scheduled work items for a default TaskScheduler. Ideally I could to use [TaskSchduler.GetScheduleTasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.getscheduledtasks.aspx) but this method is protected.

An obvious solution is to write my own Custom Scheduler and expose number of scheduled tasks. This is far from ideal solution since all I need is this number and realistically I won't write as good TaskScheduler as the default one.
I can't find the implementation of the Default task Scheduler. If I could than maybe I could inherit from it?
Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All I need is to get the number of scheduled work items for a default TaskScheduler.

Just add a counter, increment it when a new task is scheduled, decrement it when a task is finished. Don't forget to use make it thread safe, e.g. by using [Interlocked.Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) .

Comment: To be more specific I need to keep track of created Tasks and check their [IsCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.iscompleted.aspx) property. I don't any other way to find out when an actual (or any) task finished.